# Using Autocad api without opening Autocad program

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autodesk

I want help in this issue like in the title, the idea on my head is to use autocad dll files on c# references and then make a program that convert `.dwg` drawing to `.dxf` ,witch `.dxf` files open source files and you can read all the data and parse it. so i found code similar to this on the internet

```
        AxDbDocument dbxdoc;
        AcadApplication x;
        string progid = "ObjectDBX.AxDbDocument.21";
        string filename = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.dwg";
        x = new AcadApplication();
        dbxdoc = (AxDbDocument)x.GetInterfaceObject(progid);
        dbxdoc.Open(filename, "");
        dbxdoc.DxfOut(filename.Replace(".dwg",".dxf") , ""  , "");
        dbxdoc = null;
        x.Quit();
```

and i use as reference

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
```

when i run it its reatch to the line where it should to save the dxf file but it always get me this error

```
Value does not fall within the expected range
```

Please can any one help me 
thanks

Comment: Do you have a licensed copy of AutoCAD? Additionally, you are mixing using strongly typed API with late bound COM access. You can use the x Application object to open document. `var doc = x.Documents.Open(fileName)`

Comment: @reckface thanks for your reply, yea its solve the problem Thank you very much.

Comment: for who face the same problem The solution is
 '   var doc = x.Documents.Open(filename);
   doc.SaveAs(filename,AcSaveAsType.ac2010_dxf);  '